# Finding source repository for Debian packages

Tags: debian, apt

I have a Debian wheezy server which has many sources configured under */etc/apt*

There's seems to be a lot of duplicate sources, and I would like to simplify this. In order to avoid breaking anything, and miss any package upgrades, I don't want to remove any sources which are the only available source of a package.

I know that I can see the source of packages for which there are upgrades available, by using

```
apt-get upgrade --just-print
```

How can I list the sources of **all** installed packages?

Comment: have a look at `dpkg-query` `--showformat` flag

Answer (score 1):

Good question. As far as I know there is no way to find out where a package was installed from after you removed the deb-line from you `sources.list`-file.

The only way to save all the sources would look something like this:

```
% grep -h -e "^.*deb " /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | sort | uniq
deb http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted
deb http://APT.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted
deb     http://deb.grml.org/ grml-stable  main
deb http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com betsy main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main
deb     http://http.debian.net/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/linuxmint/packages betsy main upstream import 
deb http://repo.linrunner.de/debian jessie main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
```

To verify my statement I tried this:

```
% apt-cache policy | sed -n -e "/^.[0-9]/p" | cut -f3,4 -d' ' | sort | uniq
http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release/restricted
http://APT.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release/restricted
http://deb.grml.org/ grml-stable/main
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie/contrib
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie/main
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie/non-free
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie-updates/main
http://debian.lagis.at/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ jessie/contrib
http://extra.linuxmint.com/ betsy/main
http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main
http://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/linuxmint/packages/ betsy/import
http://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/linuxmint/packages/ betsy/main
http://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/linuxmint/packages/ betsy/upstream
http://repo.linrunner.de/debian/ jessie/main
http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free
http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib
http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main
http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free
http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ jessie/main
http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ jessie/non-free
/var/lib/dpkg/status
```

which basically is the same.